# Какая версия FreePascal позволяет делать пошаговое выполнение программы?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pascal

Linux Ubuntu 10.04, FP 4.2.2

Что, где и как надо настроить, чтобы делать пошаговую трассировку?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно компилировать исходники с ключиком `-g`, после чего на исполняемый файл можно натравить обычный `gdb`. А его, в свою очередь, любая нормальная IDE может использовать, тот же Lazarus.